# Javascript return true or false to callback from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using jQuery validate plugin that has a callback submitHandler. In that callback if it returns false, it aborts the submit and if it returns true it submits using the post method.

```
  $("#collection_form").validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {

        pre_ajax_submit(function (pre_ajax_return) {

            if (pre_ajax_return == 'non_ajax') {
                //something
            } else {
                //other
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So my question is: I have a function in the callback `pre_ajax_submit()`. How can I have a function return true or false in the main callback. I want to achieve the same result as this:

```
$("#collection_form").validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `pre_ajax_submit()` bring to the party?

Comment: It's another callback from ajax call, that should bring true or false which needs to go to the submitHandler, but I do not know how to make that happen

Comment: is `pre_ajax_submit` asynchronous at all? If so, you have no chance at all. you'll need to post the code for `pre_ajax_submit` for a complete answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Maybe you want a return value both from sync (`pre_ajax_return == 'non_ajax`) and async cases?

Answer (score 0):

Simply reverse the order of execution. Validate the form *after* the pre-AJAX task completes:

```
pre_ajax_submit(function (pre_ajax_return) {
    if (pre_ajax_return == 'non_ajax') {
        //something
    } else {
        //other
    }

    $("#collection_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

I'm guessing you might have lots of other things happening in your code. You should consider using Promises:

```
var whenPreAJAXFinished = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    pre_ajax_submit(function (pre_ajax_return) {
        if (pre_ajax_return == 'non_ajax') {
            //something
        } else {
            //other
        }
        resolve()
    })
})

whenPreAJAXFinished.then(function(){
    $("#collection_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```